# Can't get Eclipse to build C++ - Program g++/gcc not found in path Windows

Tags: c++, eclipse, gcc, compilation, g++

I have read all of the links I could find on stackoverflow but none of them actually contained a solution.

I am using Eclipse CDT and I have installed both cygwin64 and MinGW in trying to figure this out.

My paths seem to be correct, and I seem to be using the correct toolchains, but I still can't seem to fix it.

MINGW_HOME Variable:

```
C:\MinGW
```

MSYS_HOME Variable:

```
C:\MinGW\msys\1.0
```

PATH Variable:

```
${MINGW_HOME}\bin;${MSYS_HOME}\bin;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.0\
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Btw I do remember there being an issue with both co-existing on the same system. Have you considered trying to get only one of those to work or you need both for some reason? Further do you really need Cygwin? If you only want the GCC compiler, MinGW is more than enough. Cygwin is an emulation of an unix-like environment, which can do much more but it's a matter of whether you need that "much more" or not.

Comment: I only installed Cygwin because of desperation and trying to follow any/all instructions I could find anywhere. I only want/need one of them to work :P

Comment: When you start a new C/C++ with CDT does Eclipse give you the option of MinGW as a compiler in the settings upon filling the information for your project?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues that Eclipse CDT does not find MinGW gcc. Almost always the problem is that eclipse is 32-bit, MinGW is 64-bit or vice versa.

A solution that worked for me is to make sure that eclipse (include Java) and MinGW are both 32-bit (or both 64-bit).